# Why does my terminal letter-spacing decrease when I disable a display return from using /dev/tty?

Tags: xorg, tty, fonts, xrandr, rxvt

I've got a curious hardware situation, and I've run into a curious software quirk. I have a laptop with a broken screen that I have hooked up to an external display. I start up an X session and open a urxvt terminal. With the setting `URxvt.letterSpace: -1` in my Xresources file, the text in my terminal displays like this:

[image: Normally spaced text in urxvt]

Now I don't want the broken built-in screen still on, so I disable it with the line:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

If I open a new terminal now, the text will appear as it does above. But after logging into `/dev/tty2` and then coming back to my graphical X session and opening up a new terminal, the text displays like this with the letter-spacing much tighter than before:

[image: Much tighter text in URxvt]

Reloading my Xresources file doesn't fix this. But increasing the value of `URxvt.letterSpace` from `-1` to `0` and then reloading does appear to return the letter-spacing to what it was originally, so it seems that somewhere, after logging into `/dev/tty`, an extra -1 is being added to my letter-spacing.

Why does this happen? Why does going into a `/dev/tty` decrease the letter-spacing like this?

Comment: Is this reproducible? Is `letterSpace` set to -1 every time you switch to `/dev/tty2`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen *every* time, but I'm not sure what I'm doing in `/dev/tty` that triggers it. The only way I've figured out to reset this effect is to restart the computer (maybe just restart the Xsession?). I'll play around and reply if I discover more concrete steps to reproduce this.

Comment: And it doesn't appear that the value of `letterSpace` is actually being changed with this happens. The value of `URxvt.letterSpace` is -1 in both of those images in the question. It looks like another -1 is getting added somewhere for some reason.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev , I've made discovery. I'll add details in the post.

Comment: Sounds kind of like display driver weirdness, which acts like deep magic from normal userspace's perspective (my usual fix for problems along these lines is "update kernel and try again"; it sometimes works).

Comment: @TomHunt Haha thanks. The kernel is all up to date though. Version 4.10.6-1 on Arch Linux. :)

Comment: This looks actually like a different, more compressed font variant with a bit more weight. I think it's possible the X server rearranges font tables when it's started up again switching VTs back, and if you've several matching fonts, it might pick a different one. That's just a theory, though.

Comment: Could you post the output from `xrand` before and after disabling LVDS1? Just to check that you are dealing with exactly the same values.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I no longer have the curious hardware setup of a laptop with a broken screen and external display, and I can't seem to reproduce this error on my current setup.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have any font settings in `.Xdefaults`?

Add (or remove) lines in `.Xdefaults` to specify a font and size.

```
! -- Fonts -- !
URxvt.font:xft:Monospace:pixelsize=15
```

There may be several in the `.Xdefaults` file that the system picks from. Remove or comment out the ones you don't want or add the one you do.

This helped me set a particular size and font for my X sessions in the past.

Comment: Nope. I had deleted `.Xdefaults` so that only `.Xresources` is read from.